# Why would ClientDataSet's Locate method fail to find a record that exists?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Every once in awhile, in ways that seem unpredictable to me, the code line

```
if not CDS.Locate('Name',aName,[]) then ...
```

resolves true (*i.e.*, cannot find the string `aName` in the field 'Name') even though I know there *is* a record. I can close and reopen the application, load the exact same file, run the exact same command--repeat all my actions, in other words--and have everything work as expected the next time through. And the time after that. I can even just reopen the same file, and the code will run as expected ... I don't know what the issue is and, frankly, with something intermittent like this I don't even know where to look!

Any thoughts about where to start? ...

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a case sensitivity issue.  The second--if the name is coming from user input at least--is a typo.  Have you accounted for both possibilities?

Comment: Good points. The name already exists, it's copied from elsewhere, and I don't understand why it would seemingly be copied differently from one program execution to another. Still, the point makes a lot of sense; I'm going to search line by line on the off chance I did something dumb like Trim(aName) in one place and not another. ... Thanks for responding, I appreciate it (as always).

Comment: Is it possible that the name was inserted but not posted? (Ie sitting in a buffer and not saved?)

Comment: Sort of(?)...If aName isn't found, CDS goes into Insert mode to create and ultimately, I believe, Post the new record. I wonder if I could be inadvertently creating multiple records that are nearly identical (more or less same name)? ... Doesn't seem to be the case when I scan a couple of my data files in Notepad, but I should look at more of them before deciding conclusively. ... Thanks for responding; this is definitely something a newbie like me should watch for.

Comment: I would also verify you aren't sanitizing the data at any point.

Comment: Just for clarity - please change the condition to `if not CDS.Locate(...) then`

Comment: Instead of viewing your data file in Notepad, why not create a simple app with a `DBGrid` so you can see the actual rows and columns? It's even easy to add `Locate` capability, and you have a useful tool for debugging this sort of issue. The basic app can be done with almost zero lines of code, and should take about 10 minutes to throw together.

Comment: @KenWhite -- The actual data file has more in it than CDS's data, and even CDS has another dataset nested inside, but it is a good idea. If I don't figure out what's going on pretty soon I may put in the time to create the kind of viewer you're talking about; I know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In delphi XE7 there is a serious problem TClientDataSet.Locate  and it does not work with some fields  look at [QualityCentral [127703]](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=127703)